# How can extract special character parameter in AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am testing AWS Lambda by Node.js 4.3.
when I request POST method in start with special character Parameters.

```
{
  "@type": "Test"
}
```

then print log is normally working, but Lambda dose not recognize '@type' params.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log(event);
  var type = event.@type;      
  callback(null, type);
};
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use the non-groovy hipster syntax:

```
event["@type"]
```